Action Adventure involving kid, toy soldier, pilot dad
I want to show an old movie to my kids and can't remember the name.
I searched on "hide", "seek", "search" and not getting any good hits.
It starts with a boy playing with a toy soldier, imagining that it is real.
(Soldier's name could be Jack Stack or Jack Black, but no hits there either. Has a beret cap.)
Then the boy encounters a dying man in a stairwell who gives him a game cartridge with secret information. Jack comes to life a few times and guides him.
An older couple is chasing him.
In the end, his dad the pilot saves him, walking dramatically out of the fire.

Questions being answered and being findable are two different things.
I assumed that it had been asked and answered, but that didn't make it any easier to find.
"80's thriller" and "Children's action movie" are pretty generic.

Unfortunately, I knew this right off the bat.  :o)
Cloak And Dagger (1984)
Taken from the Wiki:

"As the plane moves to the runway, Davey tries to summon Jack for
  help; his father hears him and identifies himself as "Jack Flack" and
  calls Davey to the cockpit."


As I suspected, I was hitting all around it. Thank you!
